# Is it possible to query multiple keys in firebase (node.js) at once?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Currently I am doing a forEach loop to populate the array based on user's favorites:

```
usersref.child(formData.openid + '/favorites').once('value', function(snapshot){
  var favlist = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(fav){
    fav = fav.key();
    ref.child(fav).once('value',function(snapshot){
      favlist.push(snapshot.val());
    });
  });
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
  response.write(favlist);
  response.end();
});
```

`usersref` is a the database for the user, `ref` is the database for the items. `formData.openid` is user's unique id.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two lists are disjunct, you'll need a separate read for each item. But to ensure all reads are done before sending the response to the client, you can use promises:

```
usersref.child(formData.openid + '/favorites').once('value', function(snapshot){
  var promises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(fav){
    promises.push(ref.child(fav.key()).once('value'));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
    var favlist = snapshots.map(function(snapshot) { return snapshot.val(); });
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    response.write(JSON.stringify(favlist));
    response.end();
  }).catch(function(error) {
    response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: This still requires the server to send multiple request to firebase, say if there are a hundred keys, it needs to request 100 times to just make a new list - which would be really slow. `promises.push(ref.child(fav.key()).once('value')` is semantically incorrect btw.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo - fixed. Requesting a reasonable number of items like this is not slow, since the requests are pipelined over a single connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786 for more on that.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work just yet, I received `(node:47780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: response.status is not a function
(node:47780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.` and there is no data output...

Comment: After changing `response.status(500).send(error);` to `response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.write('favlist  error: ' + err);
response.end();` I now have an output `favlist  error: TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer`

Comment: Looks like the problem is using `response.write(favlist);` where in `response.write()` the argument can only be a string or Buffer - so `response.write(JSON.stringify(favlist))`